# the most fashionable inner-city coffee shops?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does the word **inner-city** sound natural in the following?

> Turmeric drinks became popular in the West when customers began to request turmeric lattes at the most fashionable inner-city coffee shops.

I know it's grammatical, but does the image of "inner-city" clash with "fashionable"?

I found the sentence in an EFL magazine published in Taiwan.

Comment: It does sound slightly odd. Coffee shops of a particular kind may be found in inner cities, though, thinking of inner cities I know like NY, there are not so many of them...they are coffee shops in parts of the inner cities undergoing gentrification...

Comment: In AmE, **inner-city** is a euphemism to replace **ghetto**, the rundown 
section of a city suffering from "urban blight" which is characterized by abandoned buildings and residential buildings in a poor state of repair (often because of absentee landlords),  substandard municipal services, higher incidences of violent crime and drug-abuse, overcrowded classrooms, and a dearth of places to shop for groceries including fresh vegetables.

Comment: Is it possible for "inner-city" to refer to cities away from the coast, as in Australia?

Comment: @Apollyon: Not in AmE.  *Inland cities* is how it would be said

Comment: Is the image of the OP sentence comparable to that of a Chanel boutique in a ghetto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to me, in British culture. Some of our inner cities are deprived, and others are trendy areas. If you talk about inner-city schools, it usually means deprivation, but if you talk about inner-city restaurants or coffee shops then they can easily be fashionable.